# How to handle datagrampackets on receiving side

Tags: java, design-patterns, networking

I am trying to develop a Java networking application (using UDP) in which different types of data (different object types) need to be send, as datagrampackets, from the client to the server. I am wondering how I should handle these objects at the receiving side. How can I determine the object type at the receiving side just by the bytes that are received. Are there any design patterns which I should look for when implementing a packet handler?

Regards

Comment: You need to define a protocol that both the server and client know. For example, maybe the first byte specifies the type and the next 4 bytes define the packet length, and the next n number of bytes is your object. If you want to make it easy, use a wrapping object that contains all of the meta-data that you need to decode.